# Euler's Rotation Theorem Simple Example

Tags: geometry, intuition, rotations, visualization

I'm having trouble visualizing Euler's Rotation Theorem.

I will give a simple example.

Consider an arbitrary sphere and 3 orthogonal vectors that start from the center of the sphere and extend to the sphere's surface.

[image: image0]

Here the blue vector is pointing AWAY from the viewer.

Then rotate this sphere so the vectors now look like this:

[image: image1]

The red vector is pointing TOWARDS the viewer.

Then rotate the sphere again:

[image: image2]

Euler's rotation theorem:

> In geometry, Euler's rotation theorem states that, in three-dimensional space, any displacement of a rigid body such that a point on the rigid body remains fixed, is equivalent to a single rotation about some axis that runs through the fixed point.

However if we consider the first and last image, the only way I can imagine that the red vector displaces in that way, is for a rotation about the Green axis in the first image. However, a rotation in the Green axis guarantees the Green vector won't displace.

What would a single rotation axis look like (intuitively)?

Comment: The axis formed by $\vec G + \vec R - \vec B$ in the first image.

Comment: So in the first image, the vector would point to the top right, and towards the viewer right? I honestly don't see how a rotation around that axis can result in the Red vector displacing like it does.

Comment: Make a model (a cube will be easier than a sphere: the rotation axis goes from the center of the cube to a corner of the cube) and try it out. Visualizing things in 3D is not easy!

Comment: Yes it's correct. About "how" it's not very intuitive, but you can pick a Rubik's cube (or whatever colored cube) and rotate it 120 degree around that diagonal.

Comment: @user202729: you should make your comments an answer.

Comment: Okay, it's starting to make sense. The third dimension makes things hard to visualize  but I see how it's possible now.